# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7.0'

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to load an excel file using openpyxl library but I kept getting a value error. I also created a new excel file and tried loading the file using pandas but I still get an exception error related cell "C7".

openpyxl

```
DestFile ="C:\\Users\\yaxee\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\NBET Extraction data\\December Data Extration 2020 NBET\\XYX.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(DestFile)
```

Error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '7.0'
```

pandas

```
df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\yaxee\OneDrive\Desktop\NBET Extraction data\December Data Extration 2020 NBET\XYX.xlsx')
```

Error

```
Exception: cell name 'C7.0' but row number is '7'
```

I can post the full error script if needed.

here is the full script i'm working with:

```
 import openpyxl as xl
ExtractionFile ="C:\\Users\\yaxee\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\NBET Extraction data\\August Data Extration 2020 NBET\\NOR04082020.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(ExtractionFile, data_only=True)
daily_broadcast = wb1.worksheets[0]


DestFile ="C:\\Users\\yaxee\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\NBET Extraction data\\August Data Extration 2020 NBET\\SampleOct.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(DestFile)
peak_gen = wb2.worksheets[0]
off_gen = wb2.worksheets[1]
energy_gen = wb2.worksheets[2]
energy_sent = wb2.worksheets[3]
instlld_cap = wb2.worksheets[4]
gen_cap = wb2.worksheets[5]
onBar_cap = wb2.worksheets[6]
gen_6am = wb2.worksheets[7]
unutilized = wb2.worksheets[8]

col_count = 6

step = 2
read_start_row = 73
write_start_row = 4
amount_of_rows = 54

#peak generation capability code
for row in range(5, 34):
    a = daily_broadcast.cell(row = row, column = 25)
    peak_gen.cell(row = row-1,column = col_count).value = a.value
wb2.save(str(DestFile))

#off generation capability code
for row in range(5, 34):
    b = daily_broadcast.cell(row = row, column = 27)
    off_gen.cell(row = row-1,column = col_count).value = b.value
wb2.save(str(DestFile))

#Energy generated code
for row in range(39, 68):
    c = daily_broadcast.cell(row = row, column = 25)
    energy_gen.cell(row = row-35,column = col_count).value = c.value
wb2.save(str(DestFile))

#Energy dispatched code
for row in range(39, 68):
    d = daily_broadcast.cell(row = row, column = 27)
    energy_sent.cell(row = row-35,column = col_count).value = d.value
wb2.save(str(DestFile))


#Installed Capacity code
for i in range(0, amount_of_rows, step):
    e = daily_broadcast.cell(row = read_start_row + i, column = 13)
    instlld_cap.cell(row = write_start_row+(i/step),column = col_count).value = e.value
wb2.save(str(DestFile))


#Generation Capablity code
for i in range(0, amount_of_rows, step):
    f = daily_broadcast.cell(row = read_start_row + i, column = 15)
    gen_cap.cell(row = write_start_row+(i/step),column = col_count).value = f.value
wb2.save(str(DestFile))


#On Bar Capablity code
for i in range(0, amount_of_rows, step):
    g = daily_broadcast.cell(row = read_start_row + i, column = 19)
    onBar_cap.cell(row = write_start_row+(i/step),column = col_count).value = g.value
wb2.save(str(DestFile))

#Generation at 6am code
for i in range(0, amount_of_rows, step):
    g = daily_broadcast.cell(row = read_start_row + i, column = 21)
    gen_6am.cell(row = write_start_row+(i/step),column = col_count).value = g.value
wb2.save(str(DestFile))
```

[image: SampleOct]
[[image: Read Content, Error script][2]]

Comment: Are you trying to set a value to an integer somewhere?

Comment: Not really, I have added the full script i am working with to the question. You can have a look.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of the contents that have to be written in `SampleOct.xlsx`?

Comment: I have added it

Comment: We can't see it.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcwgr.png

Comment: What line throws the error pls?

Comment: This line "wb2 = xl.load_workbook(DestFile)"

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PwQL.png      https://i.stack.imgur.com/iujWn.png     here is the error script and the read file

Comment: I have a similar error, do you already have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when a worksheet is created with the row or the column designation with a float point number. For example, worksheet.cell(row=1.0, column=1).value = 'some value'. While Excel reads the file without any issues, having openpyxl open the file causes the error. A simple remedy is to always use an integer for the row and the column designations.